# Cassandra consistency - set of rows

Tags: cassandra

Let we have RF=3, CL=2

Appilcation does first:

1) insert into T1(c1) values(1)

2) insert into T1(c1) values(2)

3) insert into T1(c1) values(3)

then

4) select c1 from T1

Is it guaranteed that statement 4 will return 3 rows if we the app calls it immediately? I think no, it will happen only "eventually". Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you read (CL=2) + write (CL=2) is greater than your RF = 3, you always read consistent data.

So to guarantee consistency we need the read + write consistency higher than RF.